# Swift 3 created error for Facebook Graph Request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift3

I was asked to update to swift 3 and now my facebook graph request won't compile. It keeps giving me the error Value of type "Any?" has no member 'object'. It throws this error on result.object(forKey: "email") as String!)!. Before swift three it worked properly and never through that error. I am not sure how to fix it as I have not been able to read through all the new documentation.

```
 let UserEmail = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email"]).start { (connection, result, error) -> Void in


        let strEmail: String = (result.object(forKey: "email") as? String)!
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert "result" into a dictionary. For example:

let r: [String: Any]? = result as? [String: Any]

...and continue

Comment: Why did it work as it is before the change? If you know. I just want to understand what changed

Comment: The only think I know is that "result" is a value of type `Any` and you can't assume it's a `Dictionary` or an `Array`. For better results, try doing `[String: Any]` instead of `[String: Any?]`. It seems Facebook assumes there is not nil value in the dictionary result.