# Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'objectForKey'

Tags: swift, swift3, facebook-login

I want to login with `Facebook` and fetch user data from a `Facebook` account. Here is my code for the login button:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
    FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, last_name"]).start { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        let strFirstName: String = (result.objectForKey("first_name") as? String)!
        let strLastName: String = (result.objectForKey("last_name") as? String)!

        self.lblName.text = "Welcome, \(strFirstName) \(strLastName)"

    }
}
```

I am getting an error in these lines:

```
let strFirstName: String = (result.objectForKey("first_name") as? String)!
let strLastName: String = (result.objectForKey("last_name") as? String)!
```

The error:

> Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'objectForKey'

I am using `Swift 3`. I am not getting what is the solution for this..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 created error for Facebook Graph Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494003/swift-3-created-error-for-facebook-graph-request)

Comment: You need to tell compiler that what is the return type of result is?? and than you can proceed further with result

Comment: Have you try like that answer i.e suggested by El Captain. Is it working now?

Comment: no it is not working @NiravD

Comment: Try like this.
 `if let dic = result as? [String: Any] { 
        if let strFirstName = dic["first_name"] as? String, let strLastName = dic["last_name"] as? String {
             print("\(strFirstName) \(strLastName)")
        }
  }`

Comment: In Swift use **always** key subscription `result["first_name"]` rather than `result.objectForKey("first_name")` which is only related to `NSDictionary`

Comment: It worked thanks :-) @NiravD

Comment: @maitreesolanki Welcome mate :), Also in swift use generic dictionary and array instead of `NSDictionary/NSArray` and use `subscription` instead of `objectForKey` as suggested by vadian.

Comment: thank you Mr.vadian @vadian